# convert ruby hash into another format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

here is a ruby hash

```
hash = {"ss"=>1, "bc/gf"=>"120/22", "bb"=>"hh"}
```

I want to convert it to

```
{"ss"=>1, "bc"=>"120", "gf" => "22", "bb"=>"hh"}
```

what I tried

```
key_arr = has.keys.map{|s| s.split("/")}.flatten
val_arr = has.values.map(&:to_s).map{|s| s.split("/")}.flatten
Hash[*key_arr.zip(val_arr).flatten]
```

works fine for me .. but is there a more elegant solution to my problem

Comment: There is a duplicated key: `bb`. Hash keys should be unique.

Comment: `is there a more elegant solution to my problem` - I think the main problem here is that you don't see your true problem. It is not how to convert this hash, but it is why you get a hash like this one in first place. Where is the input hash coming from? Why is it so weirdly formatted?

Comment: @BroiSatse Its because what we are dealing with here are lab tests and their values... the keys will be like `height, weight , systolic/diastolic` and the values like `110, 78 , 120/80`, the blood pressures cant be separated and still we want two values for systolic bp and diastolic bp

Comment: Key "ss" maps to Fixnum unlike other keys. Is that intended?

Comment: Note: such a question would be a better fit for [CodeReview.SE](http://CodeReview.StackExchange.Com/). Rule of Thumb: if you are sitting in front of a debugger, go to [StackOverflow](http://StackOverflow.Com/), if you are sitting in front of a refactoring window, go to [CodeReview.SE](http://CodeReview.StackExchange.Com/), if you are standing in front of a whiteboard, go to [Programmers.SE](http://Programmers.StackExchange.Com/), if you are sitting in front of a blackboard, go to [ComputerScience.SE](http://CS.StackExchange.Com/), if you are he person writing on the blackboard, …

Comment: … go to [CSTheory.SE](http://CSTheory.StackExchange.Com/), if you have a problem with your co-worker, boss, or employer, go to [Workplace.SE](http://Workplace.StackExchange.Com/), if you have a problem with your client, go to [Freelancing.SE](http://Freelancing.StackExchange.Com/), if you have questions about personal computing hard- or software, go to [Superuser](http://Superuser.Com/), about server hard- or software, go to [ServerFault](http://ServerFault.Com/), if you are looking for software, go to [Software Recommendations.SE](http://SoftwareRecs.StackExchange.Com/), and if it involves …

Comment: … a database, `SELECT` an answer `FROM` the [Database Administrators.SE](http://DBA.StackExchange.Com/). For security questions, there is [Security.SE](http://Security.StackExchange.Com/), and for cryptography in particular, there is [Cryptography.SE](http://Crypto.StackExchange.Com/). Puh, I think that's all of them :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object):

```
hash = {"ss"=>1, "bc/gf"=>"120/22", "bb"=>"hh"}
hash.each_with_object({}) { |(key, value), h|
  value = value.to_s
  key.split('/').zip(value.split('/')) { |k, v|
    h[k] = v
  }
}
# {"ss"=>"1", "bc"=>"120", "gf"=>"22", "bb"=>"hh"}
```

Comment: Incorrect value for gf. It is '120/22', should be '22'.

Comment: @BroiSatse, Thank you for pointing that. updated according to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
hash = {"ss"=>1, "bb/gf"=>"120/22", "bb"=>"hh"}
hash2 = hash.inject({}) do |h, (key, value)|
  h.merge([ key.to_s.split('/'), value.to_s.split('/')].transpose.to_h)
end
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation to your solution :)